# How to fetch entire multi line Statement using grep in Unix

Tags: linux, awk, oracle11g, scripting, grep

--Oracle 11g
--Linux
I am trying to create missing objects, and want to fetch the ddl for any particular Object from the ddl of all objects in a file.
I want to fetch the ddl for one object using grep, but the create statement is broken into multi-line, and through grep only one line is getting fetched.
How to fetch complete create statement using grep or any other method to do this?

Let's say, below is the file containing many create statements for all objects, I want to fetch only create statements for only missing objects, so i grep missing object_name from the ddl_file.

> file containing all create_statement dll : create_statement_ddl.txt

```
    cat create_statement_ddl.txt

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pt_set_session_tz 
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA 
DECLARE 
   v_tz  VARCHAR2(100); 
   v_no_data BOOLEAN:=FALSE; 
BEGIN 
   v_tz:=pkg_tool.get_db_timezone; 

   IF (v_tz IS NOT NULL) THEN    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=' || ''''||v_tz||''''; 
   END IF; 

END; 
/



create or replace trigger PT_AI_CMPL_STAT after INSERT on PA_CMPL_STAT for each row 
begin 
   INSERT /*+ B1805_DDL */ INTO PH_CMPL_STAT 
   (CMPL_STAT_ID, 
    CPNT_TYP_ID, 
    CMPL_STAT_DESC, 
    PROVIDE_CRDT, 
    TAP_DEF_ID, 
    REQUIRE_ESIG, 
    LST_UPD_USR, 
    LST_UPD_TSTMP, 
    ACTION 
    ) 
  VALUES 
   (:new.CMPL_STAT_ID, 
    :new.CPNT_TYP_ID, 
    :new.CMPL_STAT_DESC, 
    :new.PROVIDE_CRDT, 
    :new.TAP_DEF_ID, 
    :new.REQUIRE_ESIG, 
    :new.LST_UPD_USR, 
    :new.LST_UPD_TSTMP, 
    'I' 
    ); 
end; 
/



create or replace trigger PT_AU_CMPL_STAT after UPDATE on PA_CMPL_STAT for each row 
begin 
   INSERT /*+ B1805_DDL */ INTO PH_CMPL_STAT 
   (CMPL_STAT_ID, 
    CPNT_TYP_ID, 
    CMPL_STAT_DESC, 
    PROVIDE_CRDT, 
    TAP_DEF_ID, 
    REQUIRE_ESIG, 
    LST_UPD_USR, 
    LST_UPD_TSTMP, 
    ACTION 
    ) 
  VALUES 
   (:new.CMPL_STAT_ID, 
    :new.CPNT_TYP_ID, 
    :new.CMPL_STAT_DESC, 
    :new.PROVIDE_CRDT, 
    :new.TAP_DEF_ID, 
    :new.REQUIRE_ESIG, 
    :new.LST_UPD_USR, 
    :new.LST_UPD_TSTMP, 
    'M' 
    ); 
end; 
/

grep missing_object_name `cat create_statement_ddl.txt` > create_object.sql
grep pt_set_session_tz `cat create_statement_ddl.txt` > create_object.sql
```

What I am getting is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pt_set_session_tz
```

What i want is  below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pt_set_session_tz 
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA 
DECLARE 
   v_tz  VARCHAR2(100); 
   v_no_data BOOLEAN:=FALSE; 
BEGIN 
   v_tz:=pkg_tool.get_db_timezone; 

   IF (v_tz IS NOT NULL) THEN    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=' || ''''||v_tz||''''; 
   END IF; 

END; 
/
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+replace+multiline+statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep is for finding regexp on individual lines and printing the result, it's the wrong tool for this. If I understand you correctly then with awk it'd just be:

```
awk '/pt_set_session_tz/{f=1} f; /^\//{f=0}' create_statement_ddl.txt
```